# Print Statements from SQL file in command prompt

Tags: sybase, sqlanywhere

I am executing a SQL file which contains basic create table and lot of insert statements from command prompt. Since there are huge number of inserts, i want to track how many inserts are done. To do that i want to add few statements describing start and end of certain section in the sql file. I want this statement printed in the command prompt itself . Is there anyway i can do this?

Answer (score 0):

Either [print](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc36272.1572/html/commands/X69372.htm) or [message](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc00801.1510/html/iqrefso/X315752.htm) will do the trick. You can follow the examples inside each link.

In some specific cases you can also simply do `SELECT "Some custom message...";`